# TCL exec command error

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to execute a command using exec, but for some reason I'm getting an error:

```
# with either
set mycmd "C:\\Windows\\System32\\nslookup.exe"
set mycmd "C:/Windows/System32/nslookup.exe"
set mycmd "nslookup.exe"
set mycmd "nslookup"

    catch {exec $mycmd} result
    puts $result
```

Result: `couldn't execute "nslookup": no such file or directory'`

```
C:\Windows>dir /B /S nslookup.exe
C:\Windows\System32\nslookup.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nslookup.exe
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this error? (using tcl8.6)

Comment: Same error for all four commands?  The error posted is for the last `set`.

Comment: can u give a try on this [file executable "C:/Windows/System32/nslookup.exe"] ? Whether its giving 1 or not as output with TCL8.6 ?

Comment: Can you tell us what `puts [auto_execok nslookup]` actually says?

Comment: @Brad its for all commands run as admin

Comment: @Donal  [file executable "C:/Windows/System32/nslookup.exe"]  gives 1 
% [file executable "C:/Windows/System32/nslookup.exe"]
invalid command name "1"
% file executable "C:/Windows/System32/nslookup.exe"
1

Comment: % [auto_execok nslookup]
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Comment: `set p "C:/Windows/System32/nslookup.exe"` and `exec $p localhost` works for me on windows 7.  What version of windows are you using?

Comment: does `set p "C:/Windows/System32/nslookup.exe 127.0.0.1"` and `exec $p` also work? That's what I'm basically trying to do (although I'm using several more nslookup options which will vary)